# Activate the 'add' option by default in Tom Select

Tags: tom-select

I've enabled the "add" option on a Tom Select, which appears at the top of the dropdown when typing in a filter term. Eg:

```
new TomSelect(target, {
  create: true
});
```

However, the closest matching option is selected (see pictured). I'd like the "add" option to be selected (highlighted/activated) by default. Is this possible?

[image: tom-select with second option highlighted]

I've figured out how to listen to the `'type'` event, which happens each time you type into the filter input, but am not sure how to select the "add" option.

Comment: I've not used TomSelect before, but based on their docs I think you want `addPrecedence` : https://tom-select.js.org/docs/#addprecedence

Comment: Oh my goodness, I don't know how I missed that! That's exactly what I needed, thank you. If you can add as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try setting `addPrecedence` to `true`.

```js
new TomSelect(target, {
  create: true,
  addPrecedence: true
});
```

Related [documentation](https://tom-select.js.org/docs/#addprecedence).

Comment: Are you able to help me with the opposite issue John?  For some reason, create:true is the default.  When I add create:false, it doesn't register, and even if I try plugins: ['no_add'], that doesn't work either.  No matter what, when I inspect element, I see; create:true.  But I do not want users to be able to create new items from the dropdown.  I am using Ruby on Rails, Bootstrap5.  Thank you!

Comment: @MonroeMann Having `create:false` or simply omitting `create` (as the default is `false`) should be sufficient.  If you're not seeing that behaviour it's a bug either in your code or one of the extensions you're using.  It's best to post a new question on here with your issue, and try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate your issue so people can see what you've done /  advise on how to resolve.  In the process of creating an MRE you may even stumble across the cause; I often find this helps a lot.

Comment: Hi John.  I created the new question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77950411/in-tom-select-createfalse-should-be-the-default-but-it-is-defaulting-to-true   Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Thanks @MonroeMann.  I can't see anything obvious wrong with your code; but I'm not familliar enough to say more (the above I could answer just from looking at the docs, this one I'd need to have played the library myself to know what the output should be)... Hopefully someone who knows `tom select` better will be able to answer your question.

Comment: Btw; are you sure you're looking at the right output when you say `This is what I see when I inspect element:`... as the output doesn't look anything like the surrounding code (i.e. `asdf` appears out of nowhere / the `h4` element preceding this control isn't shown).  It may be worth adding some more code there to prove you're showing the code that's generated...

Comment: The 'asdf' is the text I wrote in the TomSelect input box.  I took a screenshot and shared that in an update on the post, so you can see the full results of inspect element.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code either.  This is what is so frustrating.  The tom select docs say that the create: false is the default.  So what the heck is making it active?  And why does create:false have absolutely zero effect.  It's so very odd.

Answer (score -1):

Otherwise, if you want to disable "add" in the dropdown, setting addPrecedence to "false" and add the following code to the option.

```
:options="{
   create: false,
   addPrecedence: false,
}"
```

For an explanation of **addPrecedence**, see https://tom-select.js.org/docs/

Comment: This is the opposite to what was asked, in fact these are the default values anyway.